# How do I put preformatted text into a FitNesse fixture table cell?

Tags: fitnesse

I want to be able to put preformatted text (i.e. containing line breaks) into a single cell of a FitNesse fixture table. Is there a way to manipulate the FitNesse wiki markup to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use !- -! to get multiline table cells and {{{ }}} to get preformatted text. The {{{ has to be outside the !-

For example:

```
|sql|
|{{{!- SELECT *
     FROM bar
     WHERE gaz = 14
-!}}}|
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that the `{{{ … }}}` inserts `<pre> … </pre>`. This may not be what you want. I saw using setHeader / setHeaders in RestFixture. `!- … -!` was what was needed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with FitNesse release 20130530; the cell value isn't formatted and and the curly brackets appear in the rendered page.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want variable substitution within the formatted text!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to define a variable with the multi-line text and then refer to this from the table cell:

```
!define sql {  SELECT *
  FROM bar
  WHERE gaz = 14
}

|sql|
|${sql}|
```

Comment: Hmmm... It seems to work. However I prefer your approach - I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

richard's comment on [Johannes Brodwall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/587889/173497) worked for me, i.e. you don't need the ["formatted 'as is'" line/block markup, just the "'as-is'/escaping" character formatting](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide) so the following is sufficient if you don't need or want the pre-formatted style too:

```
|sql|
|!-Some text
that spans
multiple lines.
-!|
```

Answer (score 1):

This way allows you to keep a table row on the same line in your source code :

```
| col1 | col2 |
| !- col1 cell <br /> with line break -! | col2 cell without line break |
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that ended up working best for me was using a couple of the solutions listed above together. Defining a variable and using the !- -!

```
define myVarWithLineBreaks {!-This is my
text with line
breaks-!}

|col                   |col2       |
|${myVarWithLineBreaks}|other value|
```